# Mapreduce implementation

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Input data is a json file and the structure of records is:

> {id=x, h1=0.1, h2=0.3, h3=0.8, h4=0.7}.

The task is to implement a mapreduce execution to get "h" triples that contains a peak. In the previous example the output is `x-> h2,h3,h4`, because h3 value is higher than its neighborhood. My idea is to implement a map that creates record as `x->h1(0.1)`, `x->h2(0.3)`, `x->h3(0.4)`... and then a reduce that extracts peaks.

Is this the right way to proceed? Map does a step useless because the shuffle and sort step gives back more or less the  initial structure. Does it introduce overhead? Or is it something tolerable if you decide to use MR paradigm?

Comment: why use reduce, when you can solve the problem directly from the map phase (unless I am missing something)? Also, be more precise. Can h1 or h4 be peaks? What exactly is the logic that you want to identify peaks? Try to give the code for this logic.

Comment: h1 and h4 are not peaks

Comment: Does every input line has a unique id?

Comment: yes, actually they do.